# Different applications across different Git-TFS branches

Tags: git, tfs

I have an existing Git repository which contains a .NET Windows application (Solution Name:A.sln). There is a requirement for converting the application into Web based portal.I want to check-in the new .NET Web application (Solution Name: B.sln) in a new branch under the existing repository. When I try to create a new branch it is being created on the basis of the master branch code of the repository that is the Windows application codebase (A.sln). How can I check-in the new solution under a new branch in the existing repository without mixing the exist application files (A.sln codebase)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this shouldn't be in a branch. If it's a new application, it should be a new repository, or a new folder within the existing repository.